# How does Ultisnips select snippet files for the file I'm currently editing?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I have installed the [vim-ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) plugin and added some files containing snippets to the `~/.vim/snippets/` directory. (note: these files are in the snipmate format as I am in the process of switching to ultisnips from snipmate)

```
% ls -1 ~/.vim/snippets/                          
apache.snippets
awk.snippets
css.snippets
html.snippets
javascript
markdown.snippets
php.snippets
sh.snippets
_.snippets
snippets.snippets
sql.snippets
vim.snippets
```

say I am in a vim buffer and I type

```
fun<TAB>
```

Ultisnips will ask me to choose between the `fun` snippets from `sh.snippets` or the `fun` snippet from `vim.snippets`.

My question is how does ultisnips decide which snippet files to load for a given filetype, and is it possible to get a list of which snippet files ultisnips has currently loaded?

Answer (score 6):

From [`:help UltiSnips-adding-snippets`](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt) (section 4.1):

> UltiSnips iterates over the snippet definition directories looking for
>   files with names of the following patterns: `ft.snippets`,
>   `ft_*.snippets`, or `ft/*`, where "`ft`" is the 'filetype' of the current
>   document and "`*`" is a shell-like wildcard matching any string
>   including the empty string. The following table shows some typical
>   snippet filenames and their associated filetype.
>
> ```
> snippet filename         filetype ~
> ruby.snippets            ruby
> perl.snippets            perl
> c.snippets               c
> c_my.snippets            c
> c/a                      c
> c/b.snippets             c
> all.snippets             *all
> all/a.snippets           *all
> ```

So, if your current buffer's filetype is `vim`, you should only be seeing snippets from `vim.snippets` (and an `all.snippets`, if you had one).

There are a few reasons why UltiSnips would load snippets for multiple filetypes at the same time for a single buffer:

- UltiSnips supports Vim's dotted filetypes, so if your buffer's
  filetype is set to `bash.sh`, UltiSnips will load both bash snippets
  and sh snippets.
- Snippet files can also extend each other using the `extends ft1, ft2,
  ft3` syntax. C++ snippet files usually start off with `extends c`, so
  `cpp` files will load both `c.snippets`, and `cpp.snippets`.
- Bugs. If your buffer's filetype does not include both `vim` and `sh`, and neither vim.snippets, nor sh.snippets extend the other (either directly, or indirectly through yet more filetypes), then it's quite possible you've found a bug.

---

Regarding listing all loaded files... I'm not sure if that's possible, but you might be able to get something similar. The description for the `UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope` function says this (section 3.5.3 from above link):

> This function simply returns a vim dictionary with the snippets whose
>   trigger matches the current word.  If you need all snippets
>   information of current buffer, you can simply pass 1 (which means all)
>   as first argument of this function, and use a global variable
>   `g:current_ulti_dict_info` to get the result

There's also a specific example of the latter usage further down the help page.

Comment: thanks, this is a solid answer. In regard to getting a list of what UltiSnips considers to be "matching" snippet files, I found issuing the command `:UltiSnipsEdit!` will generate a list of files. This list seems to correspond to what ultisnips considers "matching" snippet files